# Infimum of an outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm stuck in this problem.

Let I a set of index and $m_i$ outer measure for all $i\in I$. Show that $\inf\limits_{i\in I}m_i$ is an outer measure.

Specifically I don't know how to show the sub-additivity.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

Let $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, $m_i = 1_{\{i\}}$, $m^*(A) = \min_i m_i(A)$. Each $m_i$ is a (probability) measure, hence an outer measure.

$m^*(\Sigma) = 1$, of course. We have $\Sigma = \{0\} \cup \{1\}$, but $m^*( \{i\}) = 0$, hence $m^*(\Sigma) \not\leq \sum_i m^* ( \{i\})$.